# POST Request returns only the ID , not the data in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, post, postman

Im trying a POST request from Postman to Mongo Database. Im getting only the ID of the object, the data is not being displayed.

Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  icon: String,
  color: String,
});

categorySchema.virtual("id").get(function () {
  return this._id.toHexString();
});

categorySchema.set("toJSON", {
  virtuals: true,
});

exports.Category = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

Route:

```
const { Category } = require("../models/category");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get(`/`, async (req, res) => {
  const categoryList = await Category.find();

  if (!categoryList) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false });
  }
  res.status(200).send(categoryList);
});

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const category = await Category.findById(req.params.id);

  if (!category) {
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "The category with the given ID was not found." });
  }
  res.status(200).send(category);
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  let category = new Category({
    name: req.body.name,
    icon: req.body.icon,
    color: req.body.color,
  });
  category = await category.save();

  if (!category) return res.status(400).send("the category cannot be created!");

  res.send(category);
});

router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const category = await Category.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      name: req.body.name,
      icon: req.body.icon || category.icon,
      color: req.body.color,
    },
    { new: true }
  );

  if (!category) return res.status(400).send("the category cannot be created!");

  res.send(category);
});

router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Category.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
    .then((category) => {
      if (category) {
        return res
          .status(200)
          .json({ success: true, message: "the category is deleted!" });
      } else {
        return res
          .status(404)
          .json({ success: false, message: "category not found!" });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: err });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

URL for POST: localhost:6426/api/v1/categories?name=Srihari&icon=%23srihari&color=srihari-icon

Base URL: localhost:6426/api/v1/categories

[Output in postman for POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go2x5.png)

```
{
    "_id": "62b58640a91799ea2bc2e1f7",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "62b58640a91799ea2bc2e1f7"
}
```

Output Im expecting is a JSON object with the Category parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your code you are assigning the return value of the save method:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  let category = new Category({
    name: req.body.name,
    icon: req.body.icon,
    color: req.body.color,
  });
  // remove category = ...
  await category.save();

  if (!category) return res.status(400).send("the category cannot be created!");

  res.send(category);
});
```

by removing it you should obtain the output you want.